# Python - Spyder 3 - Open a list of .csv files and remove all double quotes in every file

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I've read every thing I can find and tried about 20 examples from SO and google, and nothing seems to work.

This should be very simple, but I cannot get it to work.  I just want to point to a folder, and replace every double quote in every file in the folder.  That is it.  (And I don't know Python well at all, hence my issues.)  I have no doubt that some of the scripts I've tried to retask must work, but my lack of Python skill is getting in the way.  This is as close as I've gotten, and I get errors.  If I don't get errors it seems to do nothing.  Thanks.

```
import glob
import csv

mypath = glob.glob('\\C:\\csv\\*.csv')

for fname in mypath:
    with open(mypath, "r") as infile, open("output.csv", "w") as outfile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(item.replace("""", "") for item in row)
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to remove the quotes? Often they're put in because the CSV data would be ambiguous otherwise (e.g. because some values contain interior commas or newlines).

Comment: In this limited case I am, but I appreciate the sentiment.  I'm actually hoping to strip, then add back in for all values.  Currently numbers are unquoted in the file.  I know that is generally fine, but it is giving me issues with my SQL Server Bulk Insert, and I figure I'm bound to see similar issues with random characters again, might as well learn something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use csv-specific file opening and writing, I think that makes it more complex. How about this instead:

```
import os

mypath = r'\path\to\folder'
for file in os.listdir(mypath): # This will loop through every file in the folder
    if '.csv' in file:  # Check if it's a csv file
        fpath = os.path.join(mypath, file)
        fpath_out = fpath + '_output' # Create an output file with a similar name to the input file
        with open(fpath) as infile
            lines = infile.readlines()  # Read all lines
        with open(fpath_out, 'w') as outfile:
            for line in lines:  # One line at a time
                outfile.write(line.replace('"', '')) # Remove each " and write the line
```

Let me know if this works, and respond with any error messages you may have.

Comment: Oddly enough it didn't remove the quotes, but it did end up quoting every field, which was really my end need anyway, and the base code did open and copy the file, so answered as far as I'm concerned.  Thanks.  (Not sure why it didn't remove the quotes though, the code seems pretty self documenting, and with your notes it all makes sense, but I suppose I could do some reading and maybe track it down.  Thanks again.)

Comment: So turns out it didn't quote the integers, not sure how my file ended up that way.  Either way this gave me what I needed to move further.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this based on the original answer provided by u/Jeff.  It was actually smart quotes (u'\u201d') to be exact, not straight quotes.  That is why I could get nothing to work.  That is a great way to spend like two days, now if you'll excuse me I have to go jump off the roof.  But for posterity, here is what I used that worked.  (And note - there is the left curving smart quote as well - that is u'\u201c'.

```
mypath = 'C:\\csv\\'
myoutputpath = 'C:\\csv\\output\\'

for file in os.listdir(mypath): # This will loop through every file in the folder
    if '.csv' in file:  # Check if it's a csv file
        fpath = os.path.join(mypath, file)
        fpath_out = os.path.join(myoutputpath, file) #+ '_output' # Create an output file with a similar name to the input file
        with open(fpath) as infile:
            lines = infile.readlines()  # Read all lines
        with open(fpath_out, 'w') as outfile:
            for line in lines:  # One line at a time
                outfile.write(line.replace(u'\u201d', ''))# Remove each " and write the line

        infile.close()
        outfile.close()
```